# Crash in shared extension when trying to draw an image of pdf file

Tags: ios, pdf, swift3, cgcontext

I am trying to draw a pdf file in a shared extension so the user can select if they want the file to be imported into the app.

I have the following function that gets called from the Shared extension:

```
func imageFromPDFDocument( _ pdfDocument:CGPDFDocument )->UIImage?
{
    guard let page = pdfDocument.page(at: 1) else {
        return nil
    }

    let cropBox = page.getBoxRect(CGPDFBox.cropBox)        
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: cropBox.size )
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in

        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: cropBox.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return image
}
```

with some pdf files it appears that at the point:

```
ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

with nothing happening. This only happens on the device and not the simulator. Is there a memory limit to what can be done in shared extensions?

Here is a link to the file:
http://www.ud-ltd.com/testFile.pdf

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I tested it using a sample PDF, it works fine. Can you share the PDF with which ur facing issue? Also let me know how do you use this function?

Comment: I know the code works as it works in the simulator and also works with some pdf files. Please see link to file above

Comment: I try to share the file from iCloud drive from the device

Comment: I tried with shared file on iPhone device, it does not give me any crash/error, tried multiple times. Strange.

Comment: I have updated the iOS on the device and Xcode and now it is working. very very worrying.